# php replace all forms of quotes

Tags: php, replace, quotes

I have mysqldb with some in on series episodes.

But when i fetch this and echo it i get some strange square with a question mark in it.

I want to replace all these to either nothing or something more suitable.

I have googled my ass of and found solution for double quotes but i would like a function that matches all forms of quotes

here is some example

“senior tanning”

�senior tanning�

Mayor’s

Mayor�s

don't know the names of these in English that is why i posting examples :)
I started with php first time yesterday so please be nice :)

Comment: The curly quotes are "double quotation mark" (U+201C and U+201D) and "single quotation mark" (U+2018 and U+2019). The question mark is "replacement character" (U+FFFD).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you echo the contents from the database, make sure you have the charset meta tag set to utf-8.

HTML DOCUMENT

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

And in PHP before any output:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

And lastly set the MySQL transfer charset:

PDO:

```
$db->query("SET NAMES utf8");
```

Or oldschool:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
```

and while you're at it, change the `MySQL table collation to UTF8_unicode or UTF8_general`

You can even add some magic to .htaccess:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

I've had these charset problems plenty of times, so I know where to find them :)

Comment: Ohh a lot of stuff to do :)
Is it possible to set this on server level or something 
i have <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> but that just fixas the åäö problem :)

Witch is the eisiest way to do this or should i do it all every time i fetch from mysql and echo result?

Comment: The best way, if possible, is to change the MySQL table's collation to utf8-unicode or utf8-general_ci. And set PHP-MySQL transfer charset to UTF8 with the query SET NAMES utf8. Then re-import everything you have into the table. Lastly add the meta charset and the header content-type to tell the browser how to display the characters

Comment: Ok i find how to change my db to UTF_unicode but never heard of PHP-"MySQL transfer charset" is that in mysql or on the php server?

Comment: Its just a query that you run directly after connecting and selecting the mysql database. What function are you using to select your database?

Comment: $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM  `episodeview` ORDER BY  `dateAdded` DESC LIMIT 0 , 30");

Comment: Ok so, change it to this:

mysqli_query($con,"SET NAMES utf8");
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM  episodeview ORDER BY  dateAdded DESC LIMIT 0 , 30"); 

You dont have to do the set names query all the time. Just once before all the other queries

Comment: Ohh now i got rid of them without setting reading all data. But i guess if i add more data now i would´t be needing the SET NAMES utf8 since the db already are utf now?

Comment: Yes, but when you insert data from PHP into MySQL, its a good practice to set names to UTF-8. 
 Basically telling MySQL that 'the following data are utf8 charset' to prevent character issues like these.
 All well-coded frameworks do this, so it isnt new :)

Comment: hehe ok. Im not the one to put there so i cant choose it. It is XBMC thats put in the data and i just read it as is.

So i should use mysqli_query($con,"SET NAMES utf8"); every time i open a database/table to input data? Or will it understand that it is utf if i specifies utf in the mysql?

Comment: Yes. But just once. It should be the first query to run after connecting to the database. (after $con = ...) Its a good practice to set the mysql collation to utf8 as well as the php to mysql transfer charset. So does everything work now? :)

Comment: Ok so every time i open a db i should run it once and the do all my querys?

Sorry if im beeing stupid but as i said second day of php :)

Comment: Yes, exactly :) You can also just run this: mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8"). http://nl3.php.net/mysqli_set_charset

Comment: Good thanks for all your help :) Could not rate your post since i have no rep but im grateful for all the help i got :)